# Trying to add cell value in web data connection url and got error 9

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this code in Excel VBA

```
Sub myquerie()
Dim mytable As QueryTable
Set mytable = Worksheets("Sheet5").QueryTables("MyQuery")
mytable.Connection = "URL;" & Worksheets("Converter").Cells(12, 4).Text
mytable.Refresh
End Sub
```

And I get error "Subscript out of range" at

```
Set mytable = Worksheets("Sheet5").QueryTables("MyQuery")
```

Comment: Either you do not have `Sheet5` or you do not have a query called `MyQuery`.

Comment: @SiddharthRout [screenshot](https://image.prntscr.com/image/bffce3b7a1bf48b1b7e6b88b4eb462c4.png) Am I missing something?

Comment: `1` Are you running the code from the same file which has the sheet5/query? `2` Manually check if the sheetname doesn't have a leading or trailing space

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes [screenshot](https://image.prntscr.com/image/87805596846b481e80ae04a4f3b1ca5a.png)

Comment: Let's take it step by step. Ok try this. In immediate window type this `?Worksheets("Sheet5").Name` Do you get "Sheet5" or Subscript out of range" message?

Comment: I get "Sheet5".

Comment: That is strange. There is nothing wrong with the code. May I see your file? If yes then please upload it in a free file sharing site and share the link here

Comment: [File](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00170729548922099362)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `Subscript Out of Range` error because it cannot find that `QueryTable`. `MyQuery` is not a `QueryTable`. It is a `ListObject`

Any of the below methods can confirm that

```
'<~~ These both will give you Subscript out of Range error
?Worksheets("Sheet5").QueryTables(1).Name 
?Worksheets("Sheet5").QueryTables.Count
```

To confirm it is a ListObject

```
Sub WhatTheHellIsIt()
    Dim LS As ListObject
    Set LS = Sheet4.ListObjects(1)

    MsgBox LS.Name
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

> So what should I do to fix this. I'm not good in vba :/ – Venoox 8 hours ago

Declare it as a `ListObject` and then work with it. Something like this. Also `SOMEVALIDCONNECTION` below has to be a valid connection string.

```
Sub myquerie()
    Dim mytable As ListObject

    Set mytable = Worksheets("Sheet5").ListObjects("MyQuery")
    mytable.QueryTable.Connection = SOMEVALIDCONNECTION
    mytable.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Now I get error 438 Object doesnt support this property or method at the same line

Comment: How can it be :) I ran that code in your file and it is working just fine

Comment: It works but I have another error -.- Error 1004 Application-defined or object -defined error at line `mytable.QueryTable.Connection = "https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/kraken/btceur/ohlc?after=" & Worksheets("Converter").Cells(12, 4).Text`

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: What is the value of `Worksheets("Converter").Cells(12, 4).Text`?

Comment: It's a number: 1466294400 In fact it's a formula that gives this number, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Your existing conneciton string looks like `Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=MyQuery;Extended Properties=""`